# Eli5.Sklearn PermutationImportance() -- TypeError: check_cv() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, scikit-learn, eli5

```py
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=10, random_state=100)
perm = PermutationImportance(clf.named_steps['classifier'], scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv)
perm.fit(X=x_train_valid_proc, y=y_train_valid)
```

I am running permutation importance from eli5.sklearn. I keep getting this error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 cv = check_cv(self.cv, y, is_classifier(self.estimator))
 TypeError: check_cv() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I am unsure how to go about this as I am only passing 2 arguments into perm.fit()

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank You

[image: error message image]
[link to error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LusZD.png)

Comment: The error message is about `check_cv()` not `perm.fit()`.

Comment: I understand that. Its called from perm.fit()

Comment: Are you calling `PermutationImportance` properly?  Your parameters don't seem to match the documentation parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known error, fixed in the master branch of the spinoff repo, but not yet in a PyPI release. You can fix it by installing directly from github.

https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/issues/414
https://github.com/eli5-org/eli5/issues/12
https://github.com/eli5-org/eli5/blob/master/eli5/sklearn/permutation_importance.py#L214